# Как получить IP в приватной сети?

Tags: ansible

Пробовал так:

```
gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - set_fact:
        man_ip: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
      when: "item.startswith('10.')"
    - debug: var=man_ip
```

Работает почти идеально. Но на машинах с докером проблема, так как его контейнеры так же имеют адрес вида `10.x.x.x`.

Так как получить IP в приватной сети для хоста?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант смотреть информацию по интерфейсу, но тогда необходимо понимать какой именно у вас смотрит в приватную сеть:

```
$ ansible all -m setup  -a "filter=ansible_eth1"
test | success >> {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_eth1": {
            "active": true,
            "device": "eth1",
            "ipv4": {
                "address": "10.133.2.40",
                "netmask": "255.255.0.0",
                "network": "10.133.0.0"
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Comment: На разных сервисах по-разному.

Comment: Я бы наверно тогла юзал бы [Local Facts])http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) и на момент провижинга сервера ложил бы туда имя интерфейса который смотрит в приватную сеть.

Comment: @Suvitruf, кстати - _контейнеры так же имеют адрес вида 10.x.x.x_. У вас маска одна и та же для физической сети и контейнеров?

Comment: я для докера ручками сам ничего не задавал. По-умолчанию так использует.

Comment: @Suvitruf докер в любом случае будет на veth